# SQL query to to add a character to a string

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help formulating a somewhat complexed SQL query.

I have a DB-table called 'models' with a column called 'modelName'.

The values in modelName look typically like this: **B1-01-A-1** or **B2-01-A-1** or **A-01-A-1**

Now, to all the strings which start with B1 or B2 I want to insert a **0** before the last position.
So B1-01-A-1 will become B1-01-A-01
B2-01-A-1 will become B2-01-A-01 and so on.

However, those which start with just a letter, like A-01-A-1, will remain without change.

**So briefly:**

B1-01-A-**1** >> B1-01-A-**01**

C1-04-B-**2** >> C1-04-B-**01**

G1-02-D-**3** >> G1-02-D-**03**

etc.

**But:**

A-01-A-1 >> A-01-A-1 (no change)

A-01-A-2 >> A-01-A-2 (no change)

etc.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Ishai

Comment: all the strings which start with B1 or B2 I want to insert a 0 before the last position. - Cannot be true given c1 and g1 change in your example - so is it the case that any that the first node is a single alpha character should not change?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 8+, we can try doing a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT
    modelName,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(modelName, '^([A-Z]+\\d+-.*)-(\\d)$', '$1-0$2')
        AS newModelName
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

- `^` from the start of the model name
- `(` capture in `$1`

  - `[A-Z]+` a leading capital letter(s)
  - `\d+` also followed by a number
  - `-` dash separator
  - `.*` all following content
- `)` close `$1`
- `-` dash separator
- `(\d)` match and capture in `$2` a single digit
- `$` end of the model name

Then we build the output as `$1-0$2`, prepending a zero before the final single digit.